# Add the elements in a list up on a condition in the corresponding list in Python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have three lists

```
vr=[5, 10, 15, 20, 25]
vr_bin = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
crf= [0.0357, 0.7124, 0.1707, 0.0142, 0.0328, 0.0291, 0.0244, 0.0206, 0.0334, 1.7124]
```

where *vr_bin* and *crf* are of same length. I have to take first value of *vr* (for example 5) and compare it with *vr_bin* (for which value of `i`, `vr_bin[i] <= vr[0]`) then sum *crf* up to  `crf[i]`.

In our example, up to `vr_bin[4]` will satisfy our condition (since `vr_bin[4]` is `5` and `vr[0]` is `5`). So I want to calculate  `crf[0]+crf[1]+crf[2]+crf[3]+crf[4]`. I tried with the following code

```
total_crf = crf[vr_bin <= vr].sum()
```

But I am getting the following error `AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'sum'` Please suggest a method for solving this. Thankyou

Comment: Do you mean to say `vr[0]` instead of `vr[1]` (and "`vr_bin[4]` is `5`" instead of "`vr[4]`")?

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: Do you have `numpy` available?  It looks like you're trying to take advantage of the indexing behaviour and methods that numpy arrays have but Python lists lack.

Comment: @DSM If my arrays were numpy arrays, will my syntax work?

Comment: @RSJohn: not quite.  I think it'd be something like ` (crf * (vr_bin <= vr[:,None])).sum(axis=1)` (disclaimer: not really tested).  But a lot closer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`sum`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) is a function, not a method, but the bigger problem is that the `crf[vr_bin <= vr]` notation you're trying to use doesn't do what you think it does in Python.  Instead, you have to iterate over the lists the long way, summing up as you go.  (Fortunately, you can iterate over `vr_bin` and `crf` at the same time with [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip).)

```
result = 0
for (v, c) in zip(vr_bin, crf):
    if v <= vr[0]:
        result += c
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score 3):

You are getting that error because `sum()` is a function, not a method:

```
>>> x = [1, 2]
>>> sum(x)
3
>>> x.sum() #Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'sum'
>>>
```

Here is code that works:

```
ind = [i for i in range(len(vr_bin)) if vr_bin[i] <= vr[0]]
round(sum(crf[i] for i in range(max(ind)+1)), 3)
```

Which runs as:

```
>>> vr=[5, 10, 15, 20, 25]
>>> vr_bin = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
>>> crf= [0.0357, 0.7124, 0.1707, 0.0142, 0.0328, 0.0291, 0.0244, 0.0206, 0.0334, 1.7124]
>>> ind = [i for i in range(len(vr_bin)) if vr_bin[i] <= vr[0]]
>>> round(sum(crf[i] for i in range(max(ind)+1)), 3)
0.933
>>>
```

Comment: I think your range limit is off by one.

Comment: Thanks @ToClickorNottoClick for your research in my problem and your correct explanation of my error. Both of your answer works for me.